# How to retrieve the value(s) of a parameter declared with vararg in an enum in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, optional-arguments

I am new to Kotlin and I have an enum containing many values, those values refer to different states my application has.

Now I need to log something whenever the app enters a state but some state in the enum can log more than one thing (based on other parameters coming from outside the app) and some state does not need to log something.

Here is my enum:

```
enum class StateName(vararg log: String) {
    FIRST_CONNECTION(), // no parameter here
    AUTHORIZATION_CHECK("message 1", "message 2"),
    HANDSHAKE_SUCCESS("message")
    //...
}
```

If had declared the enum with a single obligatory parameter `StateName(var log: String)` I could have used `HANDSHAKE_SUCCESS.log` to retrieve its value but with `vararg` the IDE (android studio) does not find `log` at all.

So how can I retrieve my string with something like `log[0]`?

**Note**:

- My enum is already defined (without parameters) and in use in my application and I can't use a different method of changing the actual state/adding a logging functionality
- I need to use Kotlin even if I just started learning as the project was written with this language so I just want to know if (and how) I can do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
enum class StateName(vararg val log: String)
```

This way you can access the log

Comment: Wow, was that simple? I feel dumb. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a variable inside enum which will hold all the arguments like below:

```
  enum class StateName( vararg log: String) {
        FIRST_CONNECTION(), // no parameter here
        AUTHORIZATION_CHECK("message 1", "message 2"),
        HANDSHAKE_SUCCESS("message");

        public var logParams:Array<out String>

        init{
             logParams=log
        }

    }
```

And to print the param corresponding to particular enum, you can iterate like below:

```
 for (item in StateName.AUTHORIZATION_CHECK.logParams) {
           println("item = "+item)
 }
```

Comment: Doing simply `vararg val log: String` works